# Hosted CRM system with an API?

Tags: web-services, email, crm

I apologize if this is slightly off-topic.

I'm hoping to find a software-as-a-service CRM system that can be easily integrated with our custom user management application. Fundamentally, we have user our own accounts and provide services to these registered users; frequently, we have email conversations with people that own these accounts - it would be great if our CRM interface would suddenly light up with the record of these conversations.

Here's my dream solution, let me know if this is possible:
- We have a "service" email alias; i'd want to add the "track@GreatCrmVendor.com" to that alias so that all emails are CC'd to our CRM vendor.
- In the admin UI for our app, I'd love to have access to the emails that the CRM vendor has captured for us - something like a REST-based web service call that aks "give me all email headers for customer with email X".

Do you know of such CRM vendor?

**Clarification**: I know how to build such a catch-all email account, parse the emails, record them in the database and all... I just don't want to invest the development time in it, I'm hoping we can just integrate with a good off-the-shelf solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce.com has an extensive SOAP API for what I understand.

http://www.salesforce.com/developer/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.advancedsps.com/?gclid=CPnlpuXL95UCFQRfagodDR554w

Answer (score 0):

Try this:[link text](http://www.highrisehq.com)

It plays well with email - AND has an API if you want to do integration...

The links to info on email integration is on the above page, as well as developer API's

<< DISCLAIMER: not employed by them, just a happy customer >>

Comment: very interesting... thank you! And the funniest thing is, my marketing people are already toying with that system.

Answer (score 0):

There are several apps in the Salesforce AppExchange that claim to handle this:

- http://sites.force.com/appexchange/apex/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YR4EAM
- http://sites.force.com/appexchange/apex/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016Y7nEAE

The salesforce.com API is also pretty straightforward to use.

Answer (score 0):

Sugar CRM has an API, and they offer a hosted service.

See: http://www.sugarcrm.com/wiki/index.php?title=SOAP_Documentation